# Trouble running KIF iOS Automation Tests

Tags: ios, kif

Just finished integrated KIF into my project -- but I am having trouble getting the tests to run...

When I run my unit tests, the sample XCTest example runs fine, but the separate kif tests never execute. Further, they show up in the test navigator but when I specifically tell them to execute, they simple do not.

My KIF tests look like this:

```
- (void)beforeEach
{
    NSLog(@"starting");
}

- (void)afterEach
{
    NSLog(@"ending");
}

- (void)testSuccessfulLogin
{
    [tester enterText:@"user@example.com" intoViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Login User Name"];
    [tester enterText:@"thisismypassword" intoViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Login Password"];
    [tester tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Log In"];
    [tester waitForTappableViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Welcome"];
}
```

and subclass `KIFTestCase`

I'd love to provide more info but I'm not sure what else to say ... does anyone have any experience running KIF tests?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error message you are seeing? Is your app made accessible?

Comment: This may not be the test, but how you are running the test.  Can you explain that more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the late answer, but I was actually checking out the v1 cocoapod (pre XCTest). That will do it!!

When i switched over everything worked fine. Make sure to do this in your pod file:

```
target 'Acceptance Tests', :exclusive => true do
    pod 'KIF', '~> 3.0'
```